# How Can I click on a button that goes to another tab in a web page using python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I'm trying to get some data for a web page that has over than 40 tabs. I can get the data from the first tab andi'm trying to make a command that click on the button "next page" so i can get the data from the next page too but I'm not getting it.

> ```
> url="https://www.vivareal.com.br/venda/sp/sao-bernardo-do-campo/condominio_residencial/"
> page = requests.get(url)
> print(page)
>
> soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
> lists = soup.find_all('article', class_="property-card__container js-property-card") 
>
>
> with open('na ponta da chave.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
>         thewriter = writer(f)
>         header = ['Title', 'Location', 'Price', 'Area']
>         thewriter.writerow(header)
>
>         for list in lists:
>             title = list.find('span', class_="js-card-title").text.replace('\n', '')
>             location = list.find('span', class_="property-card__address").text.replace('\n', '')
>             price = list.find('div', class_="js-property-card__price-small").text.replace('\n', '')
>             area = list.find('span', class_="js-property-card-detail-area").text.replace('\n', '')
>     
>
>             info = [title, location, price, area]
>             thewriter.writerow(info)
>             
> browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
> browser = webdriver.Chrome()
> browser.get(url)    
> time.sleep(15)
> button = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "button.js-change-page")   
> button.click()
> time.sleep(15)
> browser.close()
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Selenium webdriver's `find_element_by_link_text()` method to locate a button with the text "Next Page" and then click it.

```
# Click the "Next Page" button
button = browser.find_element_by_link_text("Next Page")
button.click()

# Wait for the page to load
time.sleep(15)
```

This would replace looking for the `js-change-page` as this refers to the previous page button also.

You could implement more specific ways to wait for the page load, like waiting for a particular element to be present on the page, rather than using the sleep timer.